# How to disable the highlighting of faces in Emacs using web-mode.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 along with web-mode (http://web-mode.org/).

I don't need the syntax highlighting and I am looking for a way to disable this feature. I know very little about Lisp, even less Elisp.

Here are the definitions for highlighting functions: [web-mode.el:279](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/blob/master/web-mode.el#L279). I am guessing there is some vrariable I could set to `0` so the highlighting doesn't occur, but I don't know where to look (there is a part in *documentation* covering how to enable / disable features but it doesn't talk about syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed with the version 9.0.96 of web-mode (http://web-mode.org)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to disable font-lock mode for web-mode.

You can specify a list of major mode exclusions from `global-font-lock-mode` via
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `font-lock-global-modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Choose "mode specific" from the value menu, ensure "Except" is selected, then select the "Repeat" option and insert ("INS") an entry for `web-mode`, and use the State menu to save the setting.

If that's the only customisation of this variable, then it's similar to:

```
(setq font-lock-global-modes '(not web-mode))
```

Comment: But then I'm afraid it will disable the custom face for when a block is folded (`C-c C-f`), right ?

Comment: You are right, if you disable font-locking, you will loose the style associated with folded blocks. The error you described in an other comment is strange ... could you post an issue on github ? I'll look at this.

Comment: @fxbois It seems that my account has been automatically frozen, I messaged the support and I'll get back to you when the issue is posted.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

`(setq web-mode-font-lock-keywords nil)`

Closed blocks (with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>) still get underlined.

Comment: I tried, but original syntax highlighting doesn't work anymore and `C-c C-f` gives me this: `** block-controls-get : invalid (28) **`.

Comment: no clue on this, it works correctly on my machine, both on emacs snapshot and emacs 24.3.1. What does `M-x` `web-mode-version` `RET` output?

Comment: Going to investigate on it, I updated web-mode from 9.0.48 to 9.0.93 and I am now facing the same issue.

Comment: I don't have such variable available, but my Emacs is 24.3.1 and my web-mode is 9.0.90 (from what is written in the file itself)

Comment: Updated to 9.0.95, no change.

Comment: @MathieuMarques try to `(require 'web-mode)` before accessing that variable, you probably just loaded the autoloads file.